# WebView start url Android 4.4.3

Tags: android, android-webview

We have a nexus 5 with the latest version of Android (4.4.3) and a hybrid web app running inside a webview.
Before this update we checked for the url inside the method ***onPageFinished***
to begin with "/" or "about:blank" to render the login page of our web app.
Something like:

```
if (url.equals("/") || url.equals("about:blank"))
   webview.loadUrl(preferences.getString("server_url",
                    getString(R.string.DefaultURL)));
```

And this is not working anymore for devices with 4.4.3

Which condition should I add to support this devices?

Comment: Since Android 4.4.3 comes with rather limited availability at the moment it might be best to add LogCat output to show what URL you receive on onPageFinished.

Comment: I'm getting "data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64," and  base 64 string after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
Before the code of the question, we were launching the webview with an image to show a loading message before the load of the app. Using:

```
  webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("/", wait_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

The wait_html parameter is an image tag inside a body tag. **That html is what I'm getting in the method onPageFinished** the first time the web view is launched as the url. This behaviour is not the same as it was in previous versions of Android.
We changed the way it was implemented to use just a boolean variable to check if it is the first time the web view is created to load the url of the server.

```
if (FirstTime) 
 FirstTime = false;
 webview.loadUrl(preferences.getString("server_url",getString(R.string.DefaultURL)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a "normal" URL instead of "/" or "about:blank". Ideally just use "http://mydomain.com/". The 4.4 WebView will behave inconsistently if you use "weird" URLs.

Also, why do you need to wait for onPageFinished at all? You should be able to just call loadUrl on a newly created WebView.